# Does quantum cohomology have an $E_\infty$-ring structure?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory

Consdier the classical singular cohomology ring $H^*(X, \mathbb{Z})$ of a manifold $X$. The $H^n(X, \mathbb{Z})$'s are the cohomology groups of a chain complex and it turns out that the multiplication lifts to an $E_\infty$-ring structure on that chain complex.

For a symplectic manifold $X$, with almost complex structure $J$, it is useful to consider the quantum cohomology ring of $X$, defined using $J$-pseudoholomorphic curves in $X$. We may now ask the same question about this quantum cohomology - is there an $E_\infty$-ring structure?

Does the mirror symmetry perspective tell us anything here?

By the way, my question is motivated by the existence of Quantum Steenrod Operations constructed by Fukaya (which I don't understand yet) which I found out from this arxiv paper today:

Covariant constancy of quantum Steenrod operations

Paul Seidel, Nicholas Wilkins

https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06432

EDIT - Is there any reference for the $E_2$ structure, or is it still conjectural?  The statement in Dustin Clausen's answer is a conjecture of Kontsevich mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11081/hochschild-cohomology-of-fukaya-categories-and-quantum-cohomology?rq=1) and which I guess is still open. But maybe this weaker consequence is known?

Indepedently of that, maybe there is a reference for the $E_1$ or $A_\infty$ structure?

Comment: I don't know anything about quantum cohomology, but if it's anything like quantum groups (about which I also know very little), you might expect to get an $E_2$ structure or something but not an $E_\infty$-structure.

Comment: Quantum cohomology is not really related to quantum groups at all.

Comment: It's always bold to claim that two mathematical objects are not related!  Anyway, at least Tim's conclusion is correct: according to my understanding, quanutum cohomology should have an $E_2$ structure but not an $E_\infty$ structur in general.  This is because quantum cohomology is the Hochschild cohomology of the Fukaya category (derived endomorphisms of the identity functor), and as the Fukaya category only a category not a tensor category this only gets an $E_2$-structure.  (Experts please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Interesting, this makes me wanna ask a simpler question: is there a geometric description of the E_1 structure on quantum cohomology that doesn’t require passing through mirror symmetry?

Comment: The A_\infty structure comes from thinking of QH as the Lagrangian Floer cohomology of the diagonal. You can phrase it in a more "quantum cohomologyish" language (counting spheres with point constraints which are required to live along an equator in the domain) but this is really the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @JonnyEvans, exactly the type of answer I was looking for - can you point me to a reference for this? (Preferably the quantum cohomology version as I’m an algebraic geometer and not very fluent in Floer theory)

Comment: @Bbb: I thought about this with YankI Lekili when we were working on this paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05842

I don't remember finding anywhere the version with spheres is written, but it would still be pretty Floer theoretic. You might find the above paper a good place to start: there's not much technical Floer theory, just lots of playing with twisted complexes. Section 7.3 has some examples where we show QH is not formal (e.g. for toric Fanos whose QH is not semisimple, or even for P^1 if you work with coefficients in Z/2).

Comment: Thanks @JonnyEvans, will try to parse this

Comment: @JonnyEvans Would you consider posting an expanded version of your comments as an answer? It looks really interesting but I don't have the right background for the paper you posted. Thanks!

Comment: @QuantumRing: If I get time, I will, though I don't think my comment answered the question! In the meantime, I can direct you to another answer I wrote to a related question https://mathoverflow.net/a/352822/10839